# Is Ruby on Rails good choice for my next web-app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I am writing this, I must admit that I am already inclined towards RoR.
I have gone through official ["Getting Started" tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and created a sample RoR app.
I have also had glance through [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html).

While creating sample app, I loved the ways Rails auto-generate a whole lot of code for me, and creates a nicely organized directory structure.

Creating simple sample app is fine but now I have following questions before choosing RoR for enterprise web app.

Following are question in my mind.

1. How would I debug my app? While working on Java + Spring, we could step through in Eclipse, read about ruby-debug which is like command prompt debugging. Aren't there any IDE debuggers?
2. How would I combine all javascripts etc?  in Java=Spring framework I had earlier used Google closure template for minification and joining all javascript files. would it allow sourcemap support?
3. Image Spiriting ? Any quick link to just look through if its possible or not?
4. Authentication and security : I am sure it must be possible in Rails to get logged in user's profile and then check what are db objects we can view and update, it will specific to one's web-app.   Can anyone give some links, to just look through if its possible or not? can we protect the URL based on roles as we can do in spring? How do we integrate FB/Google login
5. Templating : While creating sample app, realized that Rails supports templating in html  through embedded ruby tags, thats cool but having seen it work two more questions.

   5.1 : :construct like :confirm etc would depend on jquery_ujs.js, thats perhaps 
           shipped with rails, but I may not want to 'jquery_ujs.js' I may have my own 
           different styling for modal dialogs.  How do i replace jquery_ujs.js and plugin 
            something else ?

   5.2 :  app->view->layouts->application.erb.html , allows you to setup up title of all
           pages and what goes in header of all pages. 
           But I may not want the same title and header for all pages of my web-app, 
           It would be different for each page. How do we do that in rails?
6. DB :     most probably I am going to use DynamoDB as and use memcache for caching, 
           Any simple and sample code for pluging in the memcache in rails for dynamo
7. Maintaining three environment:  How to we maintain three different environment in Rails, Production, staging and dev
8. Would i be able to use less instead of css?

Comment: These are too many questions in one question.

Comment: Ruby on Rails, as a framework, is surely a good fit for an "enterprise web app". But looking at the questions you've asked, I don't think that it's **currently** a good fit for "you". You have too much way to go. And as @NielsB. stated, there are really too many questions for "a" question.

Comment: When you are learning a language, don't relate it with your prev background. Learn as a fresher, have command over what your are doing. Then start relating. The qsns you have asked are simple ones but answering them directly will not solve your concern. You need to dig each one of them and then then come back on sof

Comment: @NielsB. : But all are architectural concerns before choosing a framework, so  I thought it would make sense to have all architectural concerns consolidated in one place.

Answer (score 1):

As everything, there are more than one way to approach to every single question.

1. I usually use `pry-remote` to debug my rails application, because I use `pow` server and I use Sublime Text, but RubyMine is a nice IDE for developing Rails apps and it has a build in debugger.
2. Sprockets takes care of this and it's integrated in Rails. I use SASS and CoffeeScript, and you can generate source maps easily for them using those gems - [sass](https://github.com/vhyza/sass-rails-source-maps), [coffee](https://github.com/markbates/coffee-rails-source-maps)
3. You can use Compass to generate image sprites pretty easily. (Check out this episode on Railscasts - [Compass & CSS Sprites](http://railscasts.com/episodes/334-compass-css-sprites?view=asciicast)
4. [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem is really popular solution for authentication and for the Facebook/Google+ you can use [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) which integrates nicely with Devise. And for authorisation, a really popular solution is [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) gem.
5. You are free to use whatever JS UI library you like and for the dynamic layout content you can use `content_for` helper. You just have to add `yield :page_title` in your layout and then, call the `content_for :page_title { 'Specific title' }` in your views.
6. For this question, I don't have an answer but I am pretty sure that there is a gem that can help you with this like [Dynamoid](https://github.com/Veraticus/Dynamoid) for example
7. Rails supports different environments out of the box (testing, development, production) and you can easily add your own ones.
8. Rails has a support for SASS out of the box, but you can easily switch to LESS. Check out [less-rails](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails) gem.

Rails is pretty mature framework and the community around it is pretty good, so you can easily find a gem that can help you solve specific problem. And there are quite a lot resources around the internet.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks a ton @mirko. this was the kind off answers I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i will give a short glance

**ANSWER-1**

```
There is no such debugger like eclipse for ROR, you can use sublime_text editor for editing, Rspec is nice tool for RoR.
```

**Answer-2**

```
In RoR there is no need to combine all js files,you can write any of the .js file it will be render to application.js default
```

**Answer-3**

[Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269046/distributing-ruby-script-with-image-conversion)

**Answer-4**

```
There are gems in RoR which wil easily help you to do stuffs like authentication, omniauth etc..
```

[RUBYGEMS](http://rubygems.org/)

**Answer-5**

```
There are many ways you can easily find out asking on stackoverflow for your problem.
```

**Suggession:**

Instead of asking many question you should try to learn ruby deeply you will easily get your answers.